# What am I doing wrong? My Timeout is not working

Tags: android, post, timeout, httpsurlconnection

I have changed the Wi-Fi IP to not be able to connect.
I want that when the 5 seconds pass do something else but it waits about 20 seconds.

```
URL url = null;
HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

try {
    url = new URL("MY_URL");
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", String.valueOf(jsonArray)));

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getQuery(params));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) conn.getContent(), "UTF-8"));

    String response = reader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))

> Warning: If the hostname resolves to multiple IP addresses, Android's default implementation of HttpURLConnection will try each in RFC 3484 order. If connecting to each of these addresses fails, multiple timeouts will elapse before the connect attempt throws an exception. Host names that support both IPv6 and IPv4 always have at least 2 IP addresses.

That means, if a host has "n" IP addresses involved, it will take `n*milliseconds` time instead `milliseconds` you defiend.

Comment: But if I put 1 millisecond I have the same problem, I have to wait 20 seconds

Comment: maybe Net Connection issue then